# Unable to host django on IIS using Fast CGI (wfastcgi). Getting 500 error in browser

Tags: python, django, iis, webserver, wfastcgi

I am unable to host a basic django project in IIS. I have been breaking my head over 2 days now and help would be greeeaaatly appreciated :).

I have enabled IIS, CGI, and others under the Application Development in IIS.
This is my folder structure after creating a simple django project via the below command:

```
django-admin startproject dijky
```

Folder structure:

```
+ C:\inetpub\wwwroot
    + dijky
        + dijky
            - __init__.py
            - settings.py
            - urls.py
            - wsgi.py
        - manage.py
        - web.config
        - wfastcgi.py
```

I have copied the wfastcgi.py file into my project folder.
I have then Added a website named "dijky" with the below settings
[image: Add Website]

Under the Machine name in IIS, Clicked on FastCGI Settings, and have given the Full path and Arguments as so:
[image: FastCGI settings]

Then gave the environment variables as:
[image: FastCGI Properties - Environment Variables]


I even tried setting the WSGI_HANDLER to dijky.wsgi.application, since the file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dijky\dijky\wsgi.py has:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dijky.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Both don't work

My web.config XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="djangoappiis" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Anaconda3\envs\djangy\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dijky\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
     <appSettings>
    <!-- Required settings -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dijky" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="dijky.settings" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

After Starting the server I am not able to see the default django page that I we get on 127.0.0.1:8000.
I tried localhost:8007 on my browser but get a 500 error.


Any experts out there who can help.

Comment: Is there anything useful in the web server error log?

Comment: What exception is your code throwing?

Comment: How do I setup the logs :D

Answer (score 0):

What's the detailed error message of 500 error?

Ididn't receive 500 error with your environment variables.

If you are receiving error An unknown FastCGI error occurred.

Please try to replace your **application pool identity** to **local system**. If it make your application work, then it should be a permission issue.

The last thing to you need to do is analyze permission with process monitor and grant permission for your application pool identity.